# Posting data with axios without data key

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to post data with axios (react) like;

```
return axios.post(API_URL + 'available-times/edit', {data}, {headers: authHeader()})
```

everything fine, it works, but it posts the data like this:

```
data: {id: 1, monday_from: "11:30", monday_till: "15:00", tuesday_from: "11:00", tuesday_till: "16:00",…}
```

I don't want to have the "data" key in my object, how can i prevent it to not have the data key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't wrap `data` inside braces.

> return axios.post(API_URL + 'available-times/edit', **data**, {headers: authHeader()})

Comment: I was banging my head as parameters were not being mapped to model. Thanks @Prathap-reddy